# open-stack installation

Tags: openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

the http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack guide
asks for 3 logical private network IP address ranges:

```
Dynamic range — that has as many IPs as there are total NICs connected to the network
Static range — that has as many IPs as there are machines connected to the network
Floating IP range — that has as many IPs as instances that you'll have in your cloud
```

it is not clear to me if I need all the three ranges or just one of the three.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your network topology. This blog post has more details, see if it helps:

http://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/04/10/maas-network-layouts-for-the-landscape-autopilot/